# JAVA open the serial port and data transmit to serial port

Tags: java, windows, serial-port, rxtx

I am very new to java and for one of my project, I am trying to send a string to a serial port using java(First open the serial port), I found some libraries RxTx. Comm. Could anybody suggest me possible code example or some recently upgraded libraries?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

RxTx is already very old and not always easy to understand and use. JSSC is also outdated, if you use JSSC under Windows 10 and Java 9 your app will crash. I would recommend jSerialComm

Answer (score 0):

Another recent library is Javino middleware. You'll have to program on both sides (Arduino and Java). It works like that:

Your Java code will be like that:

```
Javino j = new Javino();
String receivedMessage = new String();
if (j.requestData("COM3","hi")) 
    receivedMessage = j.getData();
```

And your Arduino code (inside main loop):

```
if(javino.availablemsg()){
     msg = javino.getmsg();
}

if (msg=="hi") {
    javino.sendmsg("Your Value");
}

msg = "";
```

It is simple to use and install.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody seems to notice the JSerial-library? You can quickly test if this software works for You, by downloading 3 jar files ([7th IDE](https://7th-stone.com/index.php?id=14) [JSerial](https://github.com/thibautd/JSerial)) into the same directory. Adapt the program at the bottom of [this side](https://7th-stone.com/index.php?id=7) for Your needs. Of course You must set the PORT to correct values.

```
"COM9" 115200 8 0 1 0  6 PORT a!  (* help port *)
portopen
"my string to send" portwrite
portread type
portclose
```